# What is the best way to write a Scala object to Parquet?

Tags: scala, hadoop, thrift, data-warehouse, parquet

I have a Scala case class created from JSON, say case class Person(age:Int, name:String). I know I cannot write JSON to Parquet.

Can I write the case class directly to Parquet or do I need to use another format like Scrooge/Thrift or Avro? Which APIs are best to use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement ParquetWriteSupport class to write your custom class.